# Como alterar um item em um json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Tenho um Array de JSON mais ou menos assim:

`[{ id: 1, total: 50.00 }, { id: 2, total: 70.00 }]`

Gostaria de saber como adicionar/alterar um item em um `id` apenas. Como se fosse no SQL.

Por exemplo, no caso eu queria alterar o total do `id:2` como poderia fazer?

Comment: O título da pergunta diz "adicionar", mas pela sua descrição você quer "selecionar". Está um bocado ambíguo, poderia explicar melhor o que pretende? (seria talvez adicionar se não estiver lá, alterar se estiver?)

Comment: Me desculpe seria alterar o valor de um item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se queres alterar somente o valor do objeto cuja ID fôr 2, vais ter de percorrer todos os elementos/objetos dessa array. Se fizeres com um ciclo `for` podes usar o `break;` e melhorar o desempenho.

Algo como:

```
var json = [{
    id: 1,
    total: 50.00
}, {
    id: 2,
    total: 70.00
}];
alert(json[1].total); // 70
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    if (obj.id == 2) {
        obj.total = 100;
        break;
    }
}
alert(json[1].total); // 100
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u97dr92y/1/

Answer (score 3):

Não conheço o AngularJS, mas creio que o [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) pode fazer o que você quer (só não entendi pela documentação como usá-lo). Para fazer em JavaScript puro, pode-se usar [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, total: 50.00 }, { id: 2, total: 70.00 }];

var el = array.filter(function(el) { return el.id == 2; })[0];
el.total += 10;

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += JSON.stringify(array);
```

O [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) seria uma opção ainda melhor, mas não é amplamente suportada por todos os browsers.

Answer (score 1):

você pode adicionar um objeto ao array com o método `push`

```
var lista = [{ id: 1, total: 50.00 }, { id: 2, total: 70.00 }];
lista.push({ id: 3, total: 50.00 });
```

mas caso queira acessar o array rapidamente pelo `id` você pode usar um objeto ao invés do `array` em si.

```
var lista = {};
lista["1"] = { id: 1, total: 50.00 };
lista["3"] = { id: 3, total: 50.00 };
lista["5"] = { id: 5, total: 50.00 };

//Editando o valor do registro com id = 3
lista["3"].total = 300.00;
```

isto é possivel, pois um objeto json pode ser acessado de forma semelhante a um `HashMap`(Java) ou `Dictionary`(C#), então `json.Prop` é o mesmo de `json["Prop"]`.

Comment: E alterar o total do  id: 1, por exemplo ?