# Como Adicionar e remover itens de um json facilmente?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Tenho um json similar a este

```
[{id: 1, titulo: 'compra', valor: 50.00, data:'2014-10-23' },{id: 1, titulo: 'compra', valor: 60.00, data:'2014-10-24' } ]
```

Eu tenho uma função para adicionar, que adiciona um novo item e uma para remover.
A função de adicionar está ok, porém gostaria de saber como posso fazer para remover um item.

Podem haver vários itens iguais mas em datas diferentes, ou seja, vários itens com o mesmo ID só que com datas diferentes.

Comment: Olhando esta pergunta e [a anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50915/como-alterar-um-item-em-um-json), percebi que você parece entender errado o que é JSON. Ele é um formato para intercâmbio de dados, serializado como string. Não é feito para ser manipulado sem antes ser desserializado (o que todas as respostas aqui e na outra pergunta consideram que já está feito). Pode parecer uma distinção besta, mas é importante saber.

Comment: Entendi. Estou utilizando ele para deixar varias informaçoes em memoria para manipular após o fim de um processo... Creio que o que eu queira fazer possa ser feito de uma outra maneira. Mas agradeço a explicação, foi bem útil.

Comment: O que você quer fazer é correto, eu só queria deixar claro que nessa hora você não opera mais sobre o JSON, e sim sobre objetos e arrays normais do JS.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: o meu amigo... mostra a funcao de adicionar novo obj no json!! por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função abaixo remove a entrada JSON por qualquer chave.

Vai lhe servir como uma luva! ;-) ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLf5y9wo/))

```
var meuJSON = [{id: 1, titulo: 'compra', valor: 50.00, data:'2014-10-23' },{id: 1, titulo: 'compra', valor: 60.00, data:'2014-10-24' } ];

function removerPela(chave, valor){
    meuJSON = meuJSON.filter(function(jsonObject) {
        return jsonObject[chave] != valor;
    });
    return meuJSON
}

console.log(removerPela("data","2014-10-23"));
```

Comment: No caso seria pelo ID e Data... teria que filtrar pelos dois. Como seria? Porque na mesma data pode ter outros valores que não precisam ser deletados.

Answer (score 2):

Se queres remover todos os elementos da array com um certo ID podes fazer assim:

```
function removerID(id, arr) {
    return arr.map(function (obj) {
        if (obj.id != id) return obj;
        else return false;
    }).filter(Boolean);
}
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4ypk2be/

Neste caso que sugerí não alteras a array inicial. Podes sempre fazer `arr = removerID(1, arr);`, mas se quiseres mudar o array mesmo sem o passar para a função podes fazer a atribuíção dentro da função:

```
function removerID(id) {
    arr = arr.map(function (obj) {
        if (obj.id != id) return obj;
        else return false;
    }).filter(Boolean);
}
```

Uma outra alternativa é fazer um map com os indexes dos objectos que têm um certo ID mas isso só torna o código mais complexo e duvido que melhore muito a performance... de qq seria algo assim:

```
function removerID(id) {
    arr.map(function (obj, i) {
        if (obj.id == id) return i;
        else return 'foo';
    }).reverse().map(function (i) { // uso o reverse para ele usar indexes decrescentes
        if (typeof i == 'number') arr.splice(i, 1);
    })
}
removerID(1);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4ypk2be/2/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando a função [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/094n1ec4/). Dica: um id é um identificador único. Não use o mesmo id para mais de um elemento diferente.