# Como faço para editar e excluir os dados de um arquivo json?

Tags: php, json

Estou usando esse codigo para incluir e listar os dados salvos no arquivo "user.json" queria saver como faço para excluir esses dados e editalos

```
    <?php
        $users = @json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);

        if(!$users)
        $users = array();
        if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
            $users[] = $_POST['user'];
            $file = fopen('users.json', 'w');
            fwrite($file, json_encode($users));
            fclose($file);
       }
   ?>

   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="user[nome]">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome" name="user[sobrenome]">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Telefone" name="user[telefone]">

       <input type="submit">
   </form>

   <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Sobrenome</th>
           <th>Telefone</th>
       </tr>

       <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?= $user['nome'] ?></td>
           <td><?= $user['sobrenome'] ?></td>
           <td><?= $user['telefone'] ?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php endforeach ?>

   </table>
```

Comment: Você precisa de algum parametro para excluir?

Comment: sim gostaria de excluir eu consegui listar e incluir mas nao sei excluir e editar o arquivo

Comment: você consegue colocar o código completo para eu te ajudar?

Comment: Você quer excluir por qual parametro? por nome?

Comment: esse é o código completo, sim pode ser por nome mesmo

Comment: Essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50946/21339) pode te ajudar

Comment: sera que nao tem alguma forma de fazer com o php?

Comment: se nao vou tentar usar esse codigo ele é bem funcional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
$users  = json_decode($users, true);
foreach ($users  as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('valor', $value)) {
        unset($users [$key]);
    }
}
$users  = json_encode($users );
```

Comment: huum vlew vou usar esse ;) obrigado!

Comment: se a resposta der certo para você, marque-a como aceita

Comment: blz deu certo sim vlew ja marquei como aceita